# Как из строки удалить подстроку?

Tags: python, строки

Есть строка:

```
str = 'Hello, my name Bil' \
      '\nHello, my name Tim' \
      '\nHello, my name Mila' \
      '\nHello, my name Den' \
      '\nHello, my name Loki'
```

Как удалить из этой строки подстроку, где содержится определенное имя? Например, `name = 'Mila'`?
и чтобы ptint вывел:

```
Hello, my name Bil
Hello, my name Tim
Hello, my name Den
Hello, my name Loki
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотря что нужно в результате, если просто print

```py
str = 'Hello, my name Bil' \
      '\nHello, my name Tim' \
      '\nHello, my name Mila' \
      '\nHello, my name Den' \
      '\nHello, my name Loki'

name = "Bil"

for i in str.split("\n"): 
  if not name in i:
    print(i)
```

вывод будет

```
Hello, my name Tim
Hello, my name Mila
Hello, my name Den
Hello, my name Loki
```

Вообще `split()` метод создаст вот такой лист

```py
['Hello, my name Bil', 'Hello, my name Tim', 'Hello, my name Mila', 'Hello, my name Den', 'Hello, my name Loki']
```

и вот уже с ним можно делать все что угодно. Он итерируемый, изменяемый, его можно бросить в отдельную переменную и крутить вертеть как хочется

UPD для входного значения со списком. Решение не оптимальное, но будет легко понимаемое для ТС.

положим список в отдельную переменную и создадим список с именем и один пустой где будем хранить индексы для совпадений

```py
l = str.split("\n")
names = ['Bil', 'Tim']
indexes =[]
```

Теперь пробежимся для каждого элемента списка и найдем встречаются ли имена в из списка `names`, если да, то сохраним индексы для списка `l`

```py
for i in l: 
  for n in names:
    if n in i:
      indexes.append(l.index(i))
```

Теперь посмотри, что у нас хранит переменная `indexes`

```py
>>> indexes
[0, 1]
```

то есть нулевой и первый элементы не должны выводится. Можно скопировать в итоговый лист

```py
res = []
for i in range(0, len(l)):   
  if i not in indexes:       
    res.append(l[i])
```

посмотрим, что содержит `res`

```py
>>> res
['Hello, my name Mila', 'Hello, my name Den', 'Hello, my name Loki']
```

Манипуляции с индексами можно опустить и сразу обрабатывать/копировать. Здесь это больше для ясности

Comment: а что если name это список ? например `name = ['Bil','Tim']`

Comment: В зависимости что вы хотите иметь в результате. Вы можете так с помощью `splt()` создать список и изменять его. То есть не выводить `print`, а обработать список, удалить не нужные строки и только потом напечатать

Comment: ну вот у меня список который я привел в примере, как из этого списка удалить элементы в которых содержатся элементы другого списка. например если `name = ['Bil','Tim']` то print будет выдавать `Hello, my name Mila
Hello, my name Den
Hello, my name Loki`

Comment: @mikitos59 добавли в ответ UPD, в следующий раз если появляются новые трудности, то создайте новый вопрос. Это будет полезно многим в том числе и тем кто отвечает